# How to get saved as daily files instead of monthly (Python, ERA-5, ECMWF)

Tags: python, python-requests, target, data-retrieval

This is the script I currently uses to retrieve data using API, targeting "monthly" files. I need to reduce the size of a single file to spare time for both data preparation and transfer. Mainly by trying to target/write in daily files, eg. ....20151001.grib.

Since I'm a beginner in Python, I post here in hope of someone willing to help me improve this script, mostly considering the target/writing file.

Thank you!
/Josefine

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import calendar
from ecmwfapi import ECMWFDataServer
server = ECMWFDataServer()

def retrieve_era5():
"""
    A function to demonstrate how to iterate efficiently over several years and months etc
    for a particular era5 request.
    Change the variables below to adapt the iteration to your needs.
    You can use the variable 'target' to organise the requested data in files as you wish.
    In the example below the data are organised in files per month. (eg "era5_daily_201510.grb")
"""
yearStart = 2010
yearEnd = 2017
monthStart = 1
monthEnd = 12
for year in list(range(yearStart, yearEnd + 1)):
    for month in list(range(monthStart, monthEnd + 1)):
        startDate = '%04d%02d%02d' % (year, month, 1)
        numberOfDays = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
        lastDate = '%04d%02d%02d' % (year, month, numberOfDays)
        target = "/Volumes/JOSEFINE/ERA5/era5_sfc_6hr_%04d%02d%.grb" % (year, month)
        requestDates = (startDate + "/TO/" + lastDate)
        era5_request(requestDates, target)

def era5_request(requestDates, target):
"""
    An ERA5 request for analysis pressure level data.
    Change the keywords below to adapt it to your needs.
    (eg to add or to remove  levels, parameters, times etc)
"""
server.retrieve({
                "class": "ea",                                  # do not change
                "dataset": "era5",                              # do not change
                "expver": "1",                                  # do not change
                "stream": "oper",                               # do not change
                "type": "an",                                   # analysis (versus forecast, fc)
                "date": requestDates,                           # dates, set automatically from above
                "levtype": "sfc",                               # pressure level data (versus surface, sfc, and model level, ml)
                "param": "134.128/136.128/137.128/165.128/166.128/232.128/246.228/247.228",     # see http://apps.ecmwf.int/codes/grib/param-db
                "target": target,                               # output file name, set automatically from above
                "time": "00:00/06:00/12:00/18:00",                          # times of analysis (with type:an), or initialization time of forecast (with type:fc)
                "grid": "0.25/0.25",                            # Optional for GRIB, required for NetCDF. The horizontal resolution in decimal degrees. If not set, the archived grid as specified in the data documentation is used.
                "area": "90/-40/-30/120",                       # Optional. Subset (clip) to an area. Specify as N/W/S/E in Geographic lat/long degrees. Southern latitudes and western longitudes must be
                "RESOL" : "AV",
               })
if __name__ == '__main__':
    retrieve_era5()
```

Comment: Welcome @josefine! Although I consider myself reasonably fluent in Python, I have no idea what your question is about. Maybe you can add more information about what you expect the script to do vs. what it really does?

Comment: Hi @virtualnobi! I want to somewhat rewrite the following section:    
        target = "/Volumes/JOSEFINE/ERA5/era5_sfc_6hr_%04d%02d%.grb" % (year, month) to include day also, so it saves in 30 (31) files per month of data instead of 12 files per year. Can I just add (year,month,numberofDays)? Don't know if this helps you in any way...

Comment: If you want to add the day into the string (for use as filename), take a look at the section "5.6.2. String Formatting Operations" at https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=operators. You will need to a %-spec (wondering what the "%.grb" is meant to do, by the way) and a third parameter in the list, as you wrote. Every %-spec in the string is replaced by the corresponding element of the sequence following the % operator.